# How to use Postman to call a WCF SOAP Service that uses BasicHttpBinding?

Tags: soap, postman, wcf-binding

I am attempting to use Postman to call a WCF service that uses BasicHttpBinding. I am currently getting the error:

```
The message with Action 'https://server/namespace/IResults/SetRecordState cannot be processed at the 
receiver due to a ContractFilter mismatch...because of either contract...or binding/security mismatch.
```

In the Headers I set the content type to 'text/xml' and added:

```
SOAPAction : https://server/namespace/IResults/SetRecordState
```

Are there any other settings needed to tell Postman about the binding?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the body content needs to contain HTTP headers like this:

```
SOAPAction: http://domain/EndPoint
```

In addition, we have the content-type set to `"text/xml; charset=utf-8"` and some servers are picky about the type of content on the POST.